# Если SELECT id != Null то id иначе INSERT

Tags: php, mysql, sql

**Описание проблемы:** 
есть 2 таблицы `tabel_home` и `table_users` и они связаны 1 ко многим и при добавлении новой записи в таблицу `tabel_home` приходится проверять есть запись в `tabel_users`, если есть получать её `id` если нет добавлять и получать `id`.

Сейчас использую `php` для решения данное:

```
function GetUserId($user_name, $mysqli) {

    $sql_select = "SELECT id FROM tabel_users WHERE user = $user_name;";

    if($result_id = $mysqli->query($sql_select)) {
        if($result_id != Null) {
            return $result_id->fetch_assoc()['id'];
        } else {
            $sql_insert = "INSERT INTO tabel_users (user) VALUE ($user_name);";
            $mysqli->query($sql_insert);
            return $mysqli->insert_id;
        }
    } else { 
        return False;
    }
}
```

Но интересно есть более быстрый и удобный способ получений или добавление записи и получения её `id` и желательно использую `SQL`.

Comment: если айдишник надо возвращать, так или иначе, то че б так и не делать. Можно хитрый запрос сделать, но проще два таких

Comment: @АлексейШиманский так сейчас id и возвращается, но с помощью php и для этого отправляю 2 запроса SQL. Но интересует как это можно реализовать с помощью SQL или оптимизировать имеющейся код.

Comment: Еще раз повторю.. на SQL придется писать хитрый запрос, что проще оставить все так как есть

Comment: @АлексейШиманский то есть забить на изменения ради изменений? Я не знаю почему но этот код выглядит как костыль который нужно заменить, видимо я не прав.

Comment: код выглядит так из-за php. но касаемо SQL - конкретно в вашем случае будет два запроса так и так.... даже в одном запросе будет второй запрос....... упростить можно разве что попытаться вставить через `INSERT IGNORE` а потом сделать `SELECT` что-то вроде того, что написано у @Akina в **UPD**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самое простое решение - это без всяких проверок выполнить вставку. Если такой записи нет - она вставится. Если есть, то ограничение уникального индекса tabel_users(user) (надеюсь, таковой имеется? иначе всё описанное в вопросе не имеет смысла) не позволит вставить - но эту ошибку надо просто проигнорировать. После этого - неважно, какой из вариантов имел место,- запись в таблице ЕСТЬ. Значит, можно спокойно делать SELECT id для дальнейшего употребления. Иными словами:

```
function GetUserId($user_name, $mysqli) {
    $sql_insert = "INSERT IGNORE INTO tabel_users (user) VALUE ($user_name);";
    $mysqli->query($sql_insert);
    $sql_select = "SELECT id FROM tabel_users WHERE user = $user_name;";
    return $mysqli->query($sql_select));
}
```

**UPD:**

Или сразу

```
function GetUserId($user_name, $mysqli) {
    $sql = "INSERT IGNORE INTO tabel_users (user) VALUE ($user_name); SELECT id FROM tabel_users WHERE user = $user_name;";
    return $mysqli->query($sql));
}
```

PS. Поправьте return, чтобы получить второй рекордсет, который от SELECT-a. Я в пхп не силён...

Comment: Я бы не сказал что этот вариант лучше, тут в любом случаи идет 2 запроса к БД, когда у меня в части случаев просто не отрабатывает INSERT (И напомнила Python где try exsept лучше if). Да уникальный индекс стоит для поля user.

Comment: Поскольку Вы используете Mysqli - ничто не мешает передать оба запроса на сервер в одной команде. См. UPD:.

Comment: И да - у Вас в случае, когда выполняется INSERT, выполняются не два, а три запроса. Потому как для получения _$mysqli->insert_id;_ у Вас скрыто выполняется запрос _SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();_

Comment: Я перешел на ваш вариант, время почти не отличается но зато теперь не такая огромная конструкция, еще добавил подготовку запроса и проверку что все отработало и еще получаю строку, а не объект как в вашем варианте.